# Is it possible to have in a mysql transaction both select and update?

Tags: php, mysql, transactions

I'm curios if this can be achieved as I'm currently facing a bug and would like to see if putting a SELECT and an UPDATE in a transaction would fix it (if you're wondering why I'm not posting the code that causes the bug it's because it's a complex environment and I can't post all the influencing factors).

Something that I'm also interested in, related to this, is if you have ever experienced code that had and UPDATE query written **after** a SELECT query, yet the UPDATE gets executed before the SELECT (with the possibility that the script might run twice ruled out).

Comment: `not posting the code that causes the bug it's because it's a complex environment` then try reproducing in a simpler environment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what do you mean by a **transaction**.
There are two types of transactions:

- **Implicit transactons:** as in `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `SELECT`, `DELETE` statements, and in such statements there is no explicit transaction commands, and the database engine will rollback the whole statement if an error happens.
- [**Explicit Transactions:**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html) in such the enclosed statements inside the transaction are executed as a unit and either `COMMIT` the whole transaction or `ROLLBACK` .

So you can't have both `SELECT` and `UPDATE` inside one query, but you can but them inside a transaction like:

```
START TRANSACTION;
   SELECT * FROM tableName;
   UPDATE table SET something = 'other something' WHERE thirdsomething = @s;
COMMIT;
```

Then Put them in a stored procedure or a UDF.

**Note that:** `SELECT` statements do not modify data, so you might not need to enclose it in a transaction, so in your case you will have only `UPDATE` statement you can just use a stored procedure without a transaction.